Powerautomate - Not all field values being returned from List
I still consider myself a PowerAutomate newb so please be gentle :)
I have created a flow that does the following for a HR Incident Investigation SharePoint List:

Gets all items where the print flag is set
Starts loop

Gets Item
Does some formatting (example turns multichoice fields into unordered lists etc)
Creates a HTML file
Converts the HTML to PDF
Emails the PDF to the supplied email address


Ends Loop

This in general works really well and the client is very happy with it.  However, there is an issue.  The issue occurs at the Gets Item action.
What I noticed is 3 of the fields (Multiple Lines of Text) do not appear to come across in the output of the Get Item call.  They appear in the Dynamic Content List but not the output of the Get Item.  I verified this by copying the output from one of my runs to notepad++ and was unable to find the fields.  I have searched (I may just not be searching for the right thing) but I cannot find a solution and hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I have other Multiple lines of text fields and they are coming through
The fields are not all together and not at the end of the dataset
The data in these fields (in the list) is not huge, in some examples they are empty, but not all
I tried use the All and picking a view I knew had all the fields in the Limit Columns By View option of the Get Item action

I am out of ideas.  Please help

Try pulling your data into select it works exactly like output from get items

Hi Sumit, I managed to get this working, still not sure what i did.  However, I was looking at the select action you mentioned and it does seem more efficient.  So the next one I do I will look at this for sure.  I really appreciate the comment and something new to look at :)

In the end Get Item worked.  I had made some other changes to the flow but not sure what fixed it.  However, I would recommend looking at Sumit's answer as it seems like the more efficient way to do it.
